# How to properly handle secrets in a local.settings.json file when adding the function source code to a source control repository

Tags: git, security, azure-functions

I have an Azure function with a few secrets in its `local.settings.json` file.

What are the best practices when I want to share the source code of my function in GitHub?

So far I can think of the following options, but each option has some issues or challenges:

1- Remember to change the secrets in `local.settings.json` anytime I commit my changes. Once the commit is done, undo changes, so I can run the function and debug it. This option is very error-prone and tedious.

2- Add  `local.settings.json` to the .gitignore file. With this approach, people who get the code from GitHub need to remember to restore the `local.settings.json`

3- Store the secrets in Azure Key Vault. But this is too much for such little function that I am creating.

I wanted to ask here what are the best practices how to handle the secrets in  `local.settings.json` in a source control repository.

Comment: I am personally fan of the third solution and I use it in my projects. It's quite easy to configure KeyVault for Azure Functions and it solves many of the future problems. Simply create KeyVault, add all secrets there and commit local.settings.json file only with app settings (no secrets).

Comment: @PawelMaga, Key Vault is good for larger high budget projects. There is a cosot of key vault plus the cost of additional code to get the settings from key vault plus the cost of managing the certificate for the key vault plus the cost of maintaining the secrets in key vault. I can't afford that for my small pet projects.

Comment: It seems to me that you exaggerate these costs. Key Vault costs $0.03 for 10000 operations. The support is excellent, making it easy to connect to Key Vault and you do not need to have any certificates, just use the AD Managed Service Identity (use KeyVault policies). I use it both in high and no budget projects, for pet projects maintenance cost is marginal. Ultimately, it would be good and easy to keep all the secrets in the KeePass database (with a password conveyed in a different way), stored in the source code, but it will reduce the safety

Comment: @PawelMaga: It seems that you know a much quicker and more efficient way of managing app settings and local.settings.json with Key Vault. Would you be able to refer me to an article that explains most efficient way of using Key Vault for this senario?

Comment: @PawelMaga, how do use KeyVault to handle senarios where the setting name is in the binding attributes like [BlobTrigger ("ConnectionSettingName")] ?

Comment: It's not supported out of the box, but it is possible. Please see this thread and solution from CrazyTuna:  https://github.com/Azure/azure-webjobs-sdk/issues/746
It supports bindings.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

As [described here](https://www.tomfaltesek.com/azure-functions-local-settings-json-and-source-control/), you can add another config file (`secret.settings.json`) for your secrets.

```
{
    "ConnectionStrings": {
        "SqlConnectionString": "server=myddatabaseserver;user=tom;password=123;"
    },
    "MyCustomStringSetting": "Override Some Name",
    "MailSettings": {
        "PrivateKey": "xYasdf5678asjifSDFGhasn1234sDGFHg"
    }
}
```

Add your new settings file to the `.gitignore`. Then remove `local.settings.json` from the `.gitignore` and redact any secret values.

```
{
    "IsEncrypted": false,
    "Values": {
        "AzureWebJobsStorage": "UseDevelopmentStorage=true",
        "FUNCTIONS_WORKER_RUNTIME": "dotnet"
    },
    "ConnectionStrings": {
        "SqlConnectionString": "--SECRET--"
    },
    "MyCustomStringSetting": "Some Name",
    "MyCustomNumberSetting": 123,
    "MailSettings": {
        "FromAddress": "local-testing123@email.com",
        "ToAddress": "receiver@email.com",
        "MailServer": "smtp.mymailserver.com",
        "PrivateKey": "--SECRET--"
    }
}
```

Then make sure that your extra config file is included.

```
var config = new ConfigurationBuilder()
    .SetBasePath(context.FunctionAppDirectory)
    .AddJsonFile("local.settings.json", optional: true, reloadOnChange: true)
    .AddJsonFile("secret.settings.json", optional: true, reloadOnChange: true)
    .AddEnvironmentVariables()
    .Build();
```

With this technique, at least all settings are being tracked in source control. Any secret values are safely redacted.

Comment: This approach works well with settings you read in the body of your function. However, I am not sure it works with bindings that require having the connection string name in the attribute of Run function signature like [BlobTrigger ("ConnectionSettingName")] . The exmaple in the blog post uses [HttpTrigger] attrubute that does not need any setting name in the app setings.

Comment: Excellent point, @AllanXu. The `[BlobTrigger]` attribute will have no idea of the connection string in the new config file.

Comment: This no longer works

Comment: Using .NET 6 / VS 2022 I was able to use User Secrets instead. I had to remove competing nodes in local.settings.json though.

Answer (score 3):

> Remember to change the secrets in local.settings.json anytime I commit my changes

Use the `smudge-clean` mechanism. The smudge-clean is a mechanism which allows you to modify the file when it passes through the index.

The smudge/clean are filters which are runs whenever you commit file (clean) and checkout file to a working directory (smudge).

---

### ***`Smudge / clean`***

Read all about it and to set it up here:
https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Customizing-Git-Git-Attributes

> It turns out that you can write your own filters for doing substitutions in files on **commit/checkout**.
>
> These are called `clean` and `smudge` filters.
>
> In the `.gitattributes` file, you can set a filter for particular paths and then set up scripts that will process files just before they’re checked out (“smudge”) and just before they’re staged (“clean”).

These filters can be set to do all sorts of fun things.
So you can write your own filters for doing substitutions in files on commit/checkout.

[image]

Answer (score 2):

You should really use **user secrets** as described [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/app-secrets?view=aspnetcore-5.0&tabs=windows). This works for Azure Functions too. Like this, the unencrypted file at least is stored in user profile directory and cannot be read by other users on that machine.

You don't even have to register configuration source for user secrets or environment variables. That's done by the Azure Function runtime automatically. You can access configurations from **environment variables**, **local.settings.json** and **secrets.json** all the same way by injecting IConfiguration:

```cs
using Burckhardt.IoT.Compressor.Data.Function.Interfaces;
using System.Text.Json;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration;

namespace Burckhardt.IoT.Compressor.Data.Function.Configuration
{
    public abstract class ConfigurationLoader<T> : IConfigurationLoader<T>
        where T : class, new()
    {
        private readonly string _environmentVariableName;
        private readonly IConfiguration _configuration;

        protected ConfigurationLoader(IConfiguration configuration, string environmentVariableName)
        {
            _environmentVariableName = environmentVariableName;
            _configuration = configuration;
        }

        public T Load()
        {
            var environmentVariableValue = _configuration.GetSection(_environmentVariableName).Value;
            return JsonSerializer.Deserialize<T>(environmentVariableValue);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could commit your Json file without the secrets, then add the secrets locally and never stage the file again for commit.

Also, if you commit your file with secrets in the past and then commit it again without secrets, your secrets are still in the repository. You'll have to remove the file with pickaxe (check the filetree command, I think).

Comment: That is similar to the option #1 i explaine din my question.

Comment: Yes it is, but at least you don't have the overhead to remember to reset the changes. But if you stage everything with git add. then you'll have to remember to unstage it, which makes it the same.

Comment: Your second paragraph is why you shouldn't do the first - you're one accidental commit away from a royal PitA if you forget to exclude the file with the secrets.