# Is it possible to use Secret Manager tool with Azure Functions

Tags: azure, security, azure-functions

I'm just getting started with Azure Functions and I want to create a c# function with an azure queue trigger. When I user visual studio 2019 to create the solution it creates a `local.settings.json` where I am supposed to store the queue's storage account's connection string.

I get that the `local.setting.json` by default is ignored by git, but for other projects on we are using User Secrets to hold our local dev settings. The advantage is that the user secrets file is stored in the user profile a long way away from the solution, so there is no risk that it gets committed to source control.

Is it possible to have a Queue Triggered azure function with the queue's storgage account connection string stored in the user secrets?

Comment: Sorry for the late answer but yes, it is. Please see my answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66674372/6071640)